# Generic form of curl(curl F))

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, chain-rule

If vector field $F$ is $\langle P, Q, R \rangle$, where $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are each functions of $x$, $y$ and $z$, $curl F$ is:

$\langle (\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}), (\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}), (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) \rangle$

Now $curl (curl F)$ would be:

$\langle (\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x})}{\partial z}), (\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z})}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})}{\partial x}), (\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z})}{\partial y}) \rangle$

I think I can use the chain rule to simplify that, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The chain rule is of no value here...but expanding out the individual terms will help give you a nice expression in terms of mixed and repeated partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really simplify it much, but you can use the fact that the derivative of a difference is the difference of derivatives. For example: $$\dfrac{\partial\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2}-\dfrac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x\partial y}$$

Comment: Since $P=P(x,y,z)$ $Q=Q(x,y,z)$ $R=R(x,y,z)$, I would have thought, for example, that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} P$ would be multiple terms.

Comment: @johnnd, If $P$ is an arbitrary function (with second order partials to make the curl of the curl make sense), there's not much you can say about $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial x}$. If you know $P$ to be, say, a sum of other functions, or a composition of other functions, then you can use the sum rule or chain rule to say more.